# UI automated testing In-App purchases using Sandbox account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, coded-ui-tests, xcode-ui-testing

Is it possible to create automated tests that do the full loop using a sandbox testing account? 
Using xcode, I can't see how I could go outside of the xcode/iphone environment.

Comment: Could you please describe the full loop

Comment: Buy button is pressed -> IAP alerts come up, user inputs credentials and confirms purchase -> IAP purchase is complete and I can refresh the app state

Answer (score -2):

In theory, it is feasible, but IAP pays for the continuous pop-up of multiple system dialog and does not know how to solve the problem.